# Email: 「回答」vs「返事」

Tags: word-choice

In the context of email sending, in order to acknowledge an email which is better?

> 回答有難うございます
>
> 返事有難うございます

Also, if you have some rules on when to use either, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: By the way, writing ありがとう is normally written in Hiragana. I've seen a document which actually makes it a norm but cannot find now. In the real life Hiragana way is used by majority, however there are some people who use Kanji way too.

Comment: Good to know, I just made it a habit to press space after writing anything on my keyboard.

Comment: In general, you should only convert something to kanji if you know that they're the right kanji and that it's appropriate to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the content of your most recent correspondence.

> If the other person has answered an important question that you had asked previously, you can use 「（ご）[回答]{かいとう}ありがとうございます。」 as 「回答」 means "an answer to a question".

I used the word "important" because something like "How are you?" is not one of the questions I am talking about here.

The honorific 「ご」 would be a nice touch most of the time, but it would be optional if you were way "above" the other person.

> If no Q&A has been performed recently, you cannot use the word 「回答」 like above.  You can say, instead, 「お[返事]{へんじ}ありがとうございます。」 as 「返事」 only means "reply".

That honorific 「お」 is used virtually 100% of the time in this set phrase regardless of your relationship with the other person.

Comment: If you use 「返事」, does that imply the other person *did not* answer an important question? (Or in other words: are you expected to use 「回答」 when the other person answers an important question?)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie In sentences like「質問のメールに返事がきた」, 返事 itself does not imply whether he answered it properly or not. He responded, and his reply might or might not be a wonderful 回答.

Comment: If people say "hi" to you, then you say "hi" back - is that considered 返事?

Answer (score 2):

Based on own knowledge and some research:

- 返事 is an answer when there is a conversation about a particular topic. Basically it is used when addressing an oral conversation but not exclusively.
- 返信 when there was question sentence and answer sentence is provided.
- 回答 is basically an answer as a matter. For example - answer to a claim (as a thing, not its contents).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would usually use 回答 for emails?

Comment: I'd say 返事 since you are discussing some topic (even if you are not, emails are normally in the form of dialog and therefore there are answers).

Answer (score 2):

返事 = a reply
回答 = an answer

返る = to come back
答える = to answer

If you want to thank someone for answering your question, use 「回答」.

If you want to thank someone for replying to your communication, use 「返事」.